# flutter :Hide keyboard for a TextField

Tags: flutter

I have a search textfield  and when I enter the field I see the keyboard. I would like to go to another screen when the user click/select the field instead of showig the keyboard.

How do I hide the keyboard and go go to another screen when a user click on the field.

Basically, I want to create the action that Gmail is doing when you click the search button.

This is snippet of the textfield..

```
Container(
  color: Palette.WHITE,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
       TextField(
          controller: _textSearchController,
          onSubmitted: (val) {}
           decoration: InputDecoration(...)
        )
       ],
  )
)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe make it a button that *looks* like a text field but in fact, just opens the box with the actual text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **not open a keyboard** and use your TextField as basically a button to **go to another screen**:

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeOtherScreen())),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to hide keyboard at onSubmit method like below?

```
onSubmitted: (val) {
     FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  }
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `onTap` property on the `TextField` widget and you can use this to navigate to a different route. If you want to disable typing, you can set the `readOnly` property to true.

If you want to re-create the search button on Gmail, you can take a look at the Search Delegate `showMenu` method that flutter provides